# Not able to understand FAKE Code : - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I have a  sample script , and I am not able to understand a piece of code from that file , here is the code:

```
Target "Package1" (fun _ ->
  NuGet (fun p ->
    { p with
      OutputPath = DeployDir
      ReleaseNotes = ReleaseNote
      WorkingDir = BuildDir
      Publish = false
      Version = PackageVersion
      Files = [
        (@"*.dll", Some "lib", None)
        (@"*.pdb", Some "lib",  None)
      ]
    })
    "src/Client/Project.Client.nuspec"
)
```

and this target's order is last . So what is the purpose of using this target. and what is last line doing `src/Project.Client/Project.Client.nuspec` .If anyone can explain this in details , that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the indentation. The `"src/Client/Project.Client.nuspec"` string is indented *further* than `NuGet`, because it's one of the parameters to the `NuGet` function (which wants two parameters). Here's another way this target could have been written, with the same effect but different indentation:

```
Target "Package1" (fun _ ->
  NuGet 
    (fun p -> { p with OutputPath = DeployDir
                       ReleaseNotes = ReleaseNote
                       WorkingDir = BuildDir
                       Publish = false
                       Version = PackageVersion
                       Files = [
                         (@"*.dll", Some "lib", None)
                         (@"*.pdb", Some "lib",  None)
                       ]
              }
    )
    "src/Client/Project.Client.nuspec"
)
```

Or to make it even clearer:

```
let nuGetParameterFunction = 
    (fun p -> { p with OutputPath = DeployDir
                       ReleaseNotes = ReleaseNote
                       WorkingDir = BuildDir
                       Publish = false
                       Version = PackageVersion
                       Files = [
                         (@"*.dll", Some "lib", None)
                         (@"*.pdb", Some "lib",  None)
                       ]
              }
    )

Target "Package1" (fun _ ->
  NuGet nuGetParameterFunction "src/Client/Project.Client.nuspec"
)
```

Both of these snippets do exactly the same thing as the snippet you asked about. It's just that in these, it's a little more obvious that the `NuGet` function takes two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [NuGetHelper](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-nugethelper.html) the signature for NuGet function is `setParams:(NuGetParams -> NuGetParams) -> nuspecOrProjectFile:string -> unit`.

This means that the function takes a `setParams` function that creates a new set of `NuGetParams` from the default set of `NuGetParams`. And a path where to write the resulting `nuspec`file.

In your example the `setParams` function is defined as (my comments):

```
fun p ->
    { p with                      // p is the default NuGetParams
      OutputPath = DeployDir      // set OutputPath from FAKE properties
      ReleaseNotes = ReleaseNote  // Set ReleaseNotes to ReleaseNote (from FAKE)
      WorkingDir = BuildDir       // Set WorkingDir from FAKE properties
      Publish = false             // Do not publish to NuGet.org
      Version = PackageVersion    // Set Version number
      Files = [                   // Put these files from WorkingDir into the package
        (@"*.dll", Some "lib", None)
        (@"*.pdb", Some "lib",  None)
      ]
    })
```

The reason that `Target "Package1"` is the last target is to ensure that all values for the `setParams` value are valid.

Comment: Thank you  @rmunn ,@ Huusom .